# Is there a function that can convert every double to a unique uint64_t, maintaining precision and ORDER? (Why can't I find one?)

Tags: c++, double, comparison

My understanding is that

- Doubles in C++ are (at least conceptually) encoded as double-precision IEEE 754-encoded floating point numbers.
- IEEE 754 says that such numbers can be represented with 64 bits.

So I should expect there exists a function `f` that can map every double to a unique uint64_t, and that the order should be maintained -- namely, for all `double lhs, rhs`, `lhs < rhs == f(lhs) < f(rhs)`, except when (`lhs` or `rhs` is `NaN`).

I haven't been able to find such a function in a library or StackOverflow answer, even though such a function is probably useful to avoid instantiating an extra template for doubles in sort algorithms where `double` is rare as a sort-key.

I know that simply dividing by EPSILON would not work because the precision actually decreases as the numbers get larger (and improves as numbers get very close to zero); I haven't quite worked out the exact details of that scaling, though.

Surely there exists such a function in principle.

Have I not found it because it cannot be written in standard C++? That it would be too slow? That it's not as useful to people as I think?

Comment: *Doubles in C++ are (at least conceptually) encoded as double-precision IEEE 754-encoded floating point numbers.*.  Nope.  The standard states: *The value representation of floating-point
types is implementation-defined.*

Comment: The platforms that are IEEE 754 sometimes have a few deviations.  If you just want to get the bit copied over, use `memcpy` from one to the other.  If you are trying to extract the value rather than the bit pattern, you will probably want to extract the sign bit into a variable, the mantissa into a variable, and the exponent into a variable.  And flag +Inf, -Inf, and NaN somehow.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, you are right. I saw the chart on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types which just has that in "Encoding" and missed the "almost" where double is explained as : `double precision floating point type. Usually IEEE-754 64 bit floating point type `. 

So is double not even guaranteed to "fit" (have no more unique values than) uint64_t?

Comment: It is not.  It needs to be at least as large as a float, but it is perfectly legal for an implementation to make the size of a double 128 bits wide if it wanted to.  You can however `static_assert(sizeof(std::uint64_t) == sizeof(double));` to make sure that they are the same width.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are searching for some magic like it was done in back Quake 3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code Maybe you can find new magic number and become a star ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the representations of IEEE-754 64-bit floats are treated as 64-bit twos-complement values those values have the same order as the corresponding floating point values. The only adjustment involved is the mental one to see the pattern of bits as representing either a floating-point value or an integer value. In the CPU that’s easy: you have 64 bits of data stored in memory, and if you apply a floating-point operation to those bits you’re doing floating-point operations and if you apply integer operations to those bits you’re doing integer operations.

In C++ the type of the data determines the type of operations you can do. To apply floating-point operations to a 64-bit data object that object has to be a floating-point type. To apply integral operations it has to be an integral type.

To convert bit patterns from floating-point to integral:

```
std::int64_t to_int(double d) {
    std::int64_t res
    std::memcpy(&res, &d, sizeof(std::int64_t));
    return res;
}
```

Converting in the other direction is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Tried to make an edit to change the 64 to an 8 (or, really sizeof(std::uint64_t), because the software won't allow such a small edit), but it was rejected. The memcpy is clearly intended to copy 8 bytes, not 64.

Comment: From experiment, this seems to work for positive doubles. Not clear from the answer how to (confidently) extend this to negatives. Nor is it clear how IEEE-754 guarantees this will work.

Comment: @WilliamNavarre -- IEEE-754 doesn't **guarantee** that this will work. It says that with typical twos-complement hardware this will work. And on looking more carefully, this should probably use `int64_t` rather than `uint64_t`. Sigh. Edited appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I accepted your answer.